# Printing multiple lists, vertically and formatted, in Python

Tags: python, list, printing

Let's say I have four lists:

```
l1=[3,5,6]
l2=[0,2]
l3=[3,4,3,1,2]
l4=[2,3,2]
```

And I want to print them like this:

```
      2
      1  
6     3  2
5  2  4  3
3  0  3  2
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: `itertools.zip_longest`

Comment: Nobody is going to do it for you, until you show what you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.x you can use [`izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from **itertools**:

```
for i in reversed([' '.join(map(str,i)) for i in izip_longest(l1, l2, l3, l4, fillvalue=' ')]):
    print i
```

In Python 3.x you can use [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from **itertools**.

**Output:**

```
    2
    1
6   3 2
5 2 4 3
3 0 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to solve this problem by using multi-dimensional arrays to store the lists. then cycling through them checking for values to display while using an if statement to print a space if there is no value currently residing there (aka initialize the array to ***none*** where no value resides). I believe that if you structure it like that you may have some success